# Can the word "peace" be pluralised?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, abstract-nouns

Fairly self-explanatory question: can the word “peace” be pluralised? For those that are interested, the reason I ask is because a coworker just scored 60 points against me with "peaces". Triple letter, and triple word score!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, if you're playing Scrabble, then you need to look up your word in the [official Scrabble dictionary](http://www.hasbro.com/scrabble/en_US/search.cfm), not some random site on the internet.

However, for normal English usage "peaces" is not a word. The noun *peace* is a mass noun and an abstract noun and cannot be pluralized.

Comment: I wasn't looking for scrabble advice particularly; the question seemed terse without the history. `Mass noun` sounds like an interesting concept though.

Comment: @Phil Also _water_ is a mass noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It feels grammatical to have the plural of a mass noun if you are referring to more than one instance of a particular collection of that thing. For example, "the many waters of the world" (though of course this is a bit "irregular"/marked)

Comment: @Mitch I was replying to @Phil, who said that mass noun is an interesting concept, as he heard _mass noun_ for the first time. My comment was just reporting that there are other nouns that are mass nouns, not that the plural of a mass noun is never used.

Comment: Hmmm..have you never read "A Separate Peace"?

Comment: @Jeff *A Separate Peace* is one thing, but you'll note that the sequel *Two Separate Peaces* isn't nearly as well known.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: argh...yes...the comment was meant for Phil.

Comment: So there are no plural related rules for mass nouns? How about abstract nouns? Or is that part of the answer just an FYI?

Answer (score 7):

There are just a handful of uses of plural *peaces* in *[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)*:

> *…more than 20 years of having covered this story and watching so many false **peaces**, phony starts, so much posturing on all sides, that I must say I come to it with, you know, a certain degree of cynicism…*
>
> *As somebody who has tried to negotiate many **peaces**, how do you get out of a situation like that, where both sides are confident it's the other side's fault, and meanwhile, the violence and the strikes just escalate?*

(*Peaces* also occasionally sees use as a pun on *pieces*, as in [24peaces.org](http://www.24peaces.org/index.php) and the headline [“The missing peaces”](http://www.foreignaffairs.com/articles/64900/michael-d-bell-daniel-c-kurtzer-and-prem-g-kumar/the-missing-peaces).)

The language described by the OSPD bears only a passing resemblance to English. It includes plenty of words that are ten times as ridiculous as *peaces*. (I mean, *vrow*? Seriously? Oh, I see it’s a variant spelling of *vrouw*. Well OK then.)

Comment: Similarly, the few uses of _peaces_ in the BNC refer to multiple instances of peace.

Comment: And what is COCA when it's at home?

Comment: Click the link and see for yourself! It’s the Corpus of Contemporary American English, a gigantic searchable collection of English text, stuff Americans have said or written in the past twenty years. See http://corpus.byu.edu/corpora.asp for more info.

Comment: I find both of those perfectly acceptable. "Peace" is occasionally used to refer to a peace treaty or imposition of peace, which can of course be pluralized.

Answer (score 6):

A direct answer to the game of Scrabble is that "peaces" is a [legal word](http://www.morewords.com/word/peaces/). [Wiktionary says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peace):

> peace (usually uncountable; plural peaces)

I strongly suggest investing in a proper Scrabble dictionary as they are the ones used in tournaments and most online play. The words that are or are not acceptable for the game can differ from what is found in a strict dictionary.

EDIT: Apparently Wiktionary is really the only dictionary that has "peaces" for the highly irregular plural form. It is best to *not* use the word unless you are playing Scrabble.

Comment: Yeah I saw that on wiktionary too. It seemed a bit flimsy though.

Comment: I agree. But really, the only way to solve this dispute is to agree on a dictionary _before_ the game.

Comment: Haha! Don't use the word unless you're playing scrabble. That's funny.

Comment: Wiktionary is not the only dictionary listing "peaces" as a Scrabble word. The comprehensive "YAWL" (Yet Another Word List) includes "peaces". See: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/data/yawl-0.3.2/

Comment: *peaces* isn't irregular. Uncommon, sure, but it's a standard plural construction, hence most dictionaries won't bother listing it unless they list every other regular plural.

Answer (score -1):

I'm an author.  I had a need for the word "peaces" - so I used it, contrary to any criticism and despite any lack of formal authorization.  Since writers create words, it is now officially birthed into legitimate vocabulary. The context is, "Chamberlain peaces are won," in a work critical of liberal government administration.

Comment: ELU is concerned with standard English usages. Individuals may do what they want with strings.